Neovim: LSP not attaching to buffer
This is the LSP part of my neovim config
https://pastebin.com/3zMWCnhG
this is the entire init.lua file
https://pastebin.com/CuB3bMmg
I don't get why the lsp does not attach to any buffers?
When I run :LspInfo, I get
 Language client log: /Users/jgs/.local/state/nvim/lsp.log
 Detected filetype:   lua
 
 0 client(s) attached to this buffer: 
 
 Configured servers list: 

When I run :Mason however, I can see
  Installed
    ◍ astro-language-server astro
    ◍ chrome-debug-adapter 
    ◍ clangd 
    ◍ debugpy 
    ◍ deno denols
    ◍ eslint-lsp eslint
    ◍ jdtls 
    ◍ json-lsp jsonls
    ◍ lua-language-server lua_ls
    ◍ pyright 
    ◍ rust-analyzer rust_analyzer
    ◍ standardjs 
    ◍ stylua 
    ◍ tailwindcss-language-server tailwindcss
    ◍ typescript-language-server tsserver

the language servers are obviously installed. What's going wrong?
I copied this from kickstart.nvim and didn't change anything. I'm really confused why it's not working
In case you don't want to open the pastebin link, here is the part
 { -- LSP Configuration & Plugins
    'neovim/nvim-lspconfig',
    dependencies = {
      'williamboman/mason.nvim',
      'williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim',
      'WhoIsSethDaniel/mason-tool-installer.nvim',
      { 'j-hui/fidget.nvim', opts = {} },
      { 'folke/neodev.nvim', opts = {} },
    },
    config = function()
      vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd('LspAttach', {
        group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup('kickstart-lsp-attach', { clear = true }),
        callback = function(event)
          local map = function(keys, func, desc)
            vim.keymap.set('n', keys, func, { buffer = event.buf, desc = 'LSP: ' .. desc })
          end
          map('gd', require('telescope.builtin').lsp_definitions, '[G]oto [D]efinition')
          map('gr', require('telescope.builtin').lsp_references, '[G]oto [R]eferences')
          map('gI', require('telescope.builtin').lsp_implementations, '[G]oto [I]mplementation')
          map('<leader>D', require('telescope.builtin').lsp_type_definitions, 'Type [D]efinition')
          map('<leader>ds', require('telescope.builtin').lsp_document_symbols, '[D]ocument [S]ymbols')
          map('<leader>ws', require('telescope.builtin').lsp_dynamic_workspace_symbols, '[W]orkspace [S]ymbols')
          map('<leader>rn', vim.lsp.buf.rename, '[R]e[n]ame')
          map('<leader>ca', vim.lsp.buf.code_action, '[C]ode [A]ction')
          map('K', vim.lsp.buf.hover, 'Hover Documentation')
          map('gD', vim.lsp.buf.declaration, '[G]oto [D]eclaration')
                    
          local client = vim.lsp.get_client_by_id(event.data.client_id)
          if client and client.server_capabilities.documentHighlightProvider then
            vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ 'CursorHold', 'CursorHoldI' }, {
              buffer = event.buf,
              callback = vim.lsp.buf.document_highlight,
            })
 
            vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ 'CursorMoved', 'CursorMovedI' }, {
              buffer = event.buf,
              callback = vim.lsp.buf.clear_references,
            })
          end
        end,
      })
      local capabilities = vim.lsp.protocol.make_client_capabilities()
      capabilities = vim.tbl_deep_extend('force', capabilities, require('cmp_nvim_lsp').default_capabilities())
      
      local servers = {
        clangd = {},
        pyright = {},
        rust_analyzer = {},
        tsserver = {},
        lua_ls = {
          settings = {
            Lua = {
              completion = {
                callSnippet = 'Replace',
              },
            },
          },
        },
      }
      require('mason').setup()
 
      local ensure_installed = vim.tbl_keys(servers or {})
      vim.list_extend(ensure_installed, {
        'stylua', 
      })
      require('mason-tool-installer').setup { ensure_installed = ensure_installed }
 
      require('mason-lspconfig').setup {
        handlers = {
          function(server_name)
            local server = servers[server_name] or {}
            server.capabilities = vim.tbl_deep_extend('force', {}, capabilities, server.capabilities or {})
            require('lspconfig')[server_name].setup(server)
          end,
        },
      }
    end,
  },

the entire init.lua is here https://pastebin.com/CuB3bMmg
it seems like the lsp part might be just fine

[1/2] I believe this is a problem outside of your init.lua configuration. I've run it on my side on Linux with NVIM v0.9.5 and it works just fine, here's mine :LspInfo https://pastebin.com/uSHXusi5 I can see that on your side nvim-lsp is trying to save the log to a very strange path /Users/jgs/.local/state/nvim/lsp.log which looks like an invalid (or very unusual) on Linux, not sure about Windows/MacOSX. Are you using Windows? Perhaps Neovim fails to find packages downloaded via Mason.

[2/2] Use :lua print(vim.env.PATH) and then :mess, and check if [some_dir]/mason/bin appears there. Then check if packages actually appear in said mason/bin directory, and if that directory is actually valid on your OS. If that won't help, please give as more info about your environment.

Ahhh... nvm! I just nuked my ~/.local/share/nvim path and I got the same issue as yours - https://pastebin.com/aCPtD5kn - and the /mason/bin appears on my neovim's PATH env variable. However, lua-language-server is missing from /mason/bin folder, so there is something wrong with the servers table setup.

Okey, I have no idea what's going on, haha! I nuked /mason/bin and applied your config once again, now it work's just fine for some reason https://pastebin.com/sHk2GPTC I've only change formatting and removed some white spaces from yours init.lua, and now it "just" works https://pastebin.com/VHSwBtus I'm leaving this topic as I wasted so much time on it, but I'm actually curious what the issue is. Please check your setup according to my previous comments and write back. Cheers!

It turns out, the problem was being on an old version of mason-lspconfig. This was causing the issue:
require('mason-lspconfig').setup {
    handlers = {
      function(server_name)
        local server = servers[server_name] or {}

        server.capabilities = vim.tbl_deep_extend('force', {}, capabilities, server.capabilities or {})
        require('lspconfig')[server_name].setup(server)
      end,
    },

The way to pass in the handlers was different in an older version. Updating it solved the problem.
